# Send data from one function to another

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

Take a deep look at the inside of function `insertUser` and `insertMoney`

I want to send the value of id in `insertUser` to `insertMoney`
and id is a ***variable***

I have tried var idT, and `insertUser` that works but in other function that is `insertMoney` returns `""`.

Here is my viewModel :

```
var idT= ""
class AddUserViewModel(
    val mUserInfoDAO: UserDAO,
    val mTransactionDAO: TransactionsDAO,
    val mLoan: LoanDAO,
    val mBankDAO: BankDAO,
    application: Application
) :
AndroidViewModel(application) {
var viewModelJob = Job()
val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)


    fun insertUser(
    fullName: String,
    accountId: String,
    mobileNumber: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    dateOfCreation: String,
    address: String,
) {
    uiScope.launch {
        try {
            Log.d("TAG", "insertTest")
            val user = UserInfo(
                0L,
                fullName,
                accountId,
                mobileNumber,
                phoneNumber,
                dateOfCreation,
                address
            )
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           
                #*#*#*#*#*#* I WANT TO SENT VALUE OF *id* TO insertMoney #*#*#*#*#*#* 

                val id = mUserInfoDAO.insert(user)
             
   
               idT=id.toString()
                Log.d("TAG", "insertUser: $idT")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "insertContact: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}

fun insertMoney(
    amount: String,
    increasePage: String?
) {
    Log.d("TAG", "insertUserTTT: $idT")

    var bankId: Long = bankInfo.value?.get(selectedItemPosition)?.bankId!!
    uiScope.launch {
        mTransactionDAO.insert(
            Transaction(
                0L,
            
                *#*#*#*#*#HERE#*#*#*#*#*#
                // id //,
                null,
                bankId,
                null,
                amount,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                increasePage
            )
        )

    }

}
```

And I call these 2 functions in fragment :

```
   mAddUserViewModel.addUser.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (it == true) {
          
          
               mAddUserViewModel.insertUser(
                mAddUserListBinding.fullName.text.toString(),
                mAddUserListBinding.accountId.text.toString(),
                mAddUserListBinding.mobileNumber.text.toString(),
                mAddUserListBinding.phoneNumber.text.toString(),
                mAddUserListBinding.createdDate.text.toString(),
                mAddUserListBinding.edtAddress.text.toString(),
            )
         
         
            val firstMoney = "firstMoney"
            mAddUserViewModel.insertMoney(
                mAddUserListBinding.firstMoney.text.toString(),
                firstMoney
            )
            findNavController().popBackStack()
        }
    })
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions? because when you call `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` that will cause the coroutine in `insertUser` to suspend, allowing the thread of the uiScope to pickup a non-suspended coroutine (the one created in `insertMoney`). I'm guessing that you call `insertMoney` right after `insertUser` both of which return immediately because they start coroutines. Also, you should avoid using `Dispatchers.Main` if the coroutine isn't touching the UI in anyway and probably use `Dispatchers.Default` instead.

Comment: SO thanks for your help I called these functions in fragment and I get the value of edit texts and inserted them into the room. I updated my question please check it out. @undermark5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

I mixed both functions body
I remove insertMoney function and add its body to insertUser and I get the value of editText and insert it in insert User

```
 fun insertUser(
    fullName: String,
    accountId: String,
    mobileNumber: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    dateOfCreation: String,
    address: String,
) {
    uiScope.launch {
        try {
            Log.d("TAG", "insertTest")
            val user = UserInfo(
                0L,
                fullName,
                accountId,
                mobileNumber,
                phoneNumber,
                dateOfCreation,
                address
            )
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val id = mUserInfoDAO.insert(user)
                Log.d("TAG", "insertUser: $amount")
                val increasePage = "firstMoney"
                val bankId: Long = bankInfo.value?.get(selectedItemPosition)?.bankId!!
                mTransactionDAO.insert(
                    Transaction(
                        0L,
                        id,
                        null,
                        bankId,
                        null,
                        amount,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        increasePage
                    )
                )
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "insertContact: ${e.message}")
        }

    }
}
private var username = ObservableField("").toString()
fun afterUserNameChange(s: CharSequence) {
    Log.i("truck", s.toString());
    amount = s.toString()
    this.username = s.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun insertUser(
    fullName: String,
    accountId: String,
    mobileNumber: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    dateOfCreation: String,
    address: String,
    function:(Int,String,String)->Unit ,
    firstMoney:String  )  {
    uiScope.launch {
        try {
            Log.d("TAG", "insertTest")
            val user = UserInfo(
                0L,
                fullName,
                accountId,
                mobileNumber,
                phoneNumber,
                dateOfCreation,
                address
            )
             withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val id = mUserInfoDAO.insert(user)

             function (id, firstMoney,"first money")

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "insertContact: ${e.message}")
        }
    }   
  }

insertUser(......,...,..., ::insertMoney,"30")
```